# How to implement a atomic operation?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-barriers

The gcc-built-in atomic operation:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html

I need an **atomic operation**：**An add opration with CAS**. It's a little like the gcc built-in function __atomic_compare_exchange_n, but different:

1. the function prototype just like this : `bool atomic_compare_add(int &ptr, int &expected, int val)`
2. the function execute **atomicly** : `if (ptr != expected) { ptr = ptr + val; return true; } else { return false; }`

The function I want is **different** from __atomic_compare_exchange_n and __atomic_add_fetch, __atomic_compare_exchange_n means `if (*ptr == *expected) { *ptr = desire; return true; } else { return false; }` and __atomic_add_fetch means `*ptr = *ptr + val; return *ptr;`.

How to implement that operation on Linux gcc/g++?

Comment: The STL might solve your problem independent of the compilder: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Comment: The link you posted describes `__atomic_add_fetch` literally 10 lines after `__atomic_compare_exchange_n`, which seems to do what you want.

Comment: Consider changing your logic to a more common `if (ptr == expected) { ptr = ptr + value; } else { do nothing }` and use [`atomic::compare_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I've got one solution:

```
bool atomic_compare_add(int *ptr, int not_expected, int val) {
    int old_val;
    do {
        old_val = __atomic_load_n(ptr, __ATOMIC_CONSUME);
        if (old_val == not_expected) {
            return false;
        }
    } while (!__atomic_compare_exchange_n(ptr, &old_val, old_val + val, true, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL, __ATOMIC_RELAXED));
    return true;
}
```